# Dependency inject a generic struct without having to re-specify placeholder type or constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics

I'm trying to dependency inject a generic struct into a class, but I don't want to have to re-specify the generic's placeholder type again in the class as well.  That gets out of hand because any class that uses this class will have to do the same, on and on.

For instance, this works:

```
struct SomeStruct<T : CustomStringConvertible> {
    let data: T
}

class SomeClass {
    let someStruct = SomeStruct(data: 1)
}
```

However, if I want to dependency inject the `struct` into the `class`, I get an error:

```
struct SomeStruct<T : CustomStringConvertible> {
    let data: T
}

class SomeClass {
    let someStruct: SomeStruct
    //              ^
    // Reference to generic type 'SomeStruct' requires arguments in <...>

    init(someStruct: SomeStruct) {
    //               ^
    // Reference to generic type 'SomeStruct' requires arguments in <...>
        self.someStruct = someStruct
    }
}
```

So then I have to specify the placeholder type and type constraints again in the `class`:

```
struct SomeStruct<T : CustomStringConvertible> {
    let data: T
}

class SomeClass<T : CustomStringConvertible> {
    let someStruct: SomeStruct<T>

    init(someStruct: SomeStruct<T>) {
        self.someStruct = someStruct
    }
}
```

Is there some way to get around the need to re-specify the placeholder type and constraints in the class?  Why can't the class just know that `SomeStruct` holds `data: CustomStringConvertible`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You're trying to describe a concept that would allow specify a concrete (`class`) type:

```
class SomeClass { ... }
```

but using a non-concrete type as a member

```
class SomeClass { 
    let someStruct: SomeStruct // <-- non-specified generic type, what placeholder should we use?
}
```

For any concrete types, their members must also be concrete

```
// OK
class SomeClass { 
    let someStruct: SomeStruct<Int>
}
```

whereas you could allow generic members if their types is tied to a generic typeholder of the owning type (`SomeClass`) itself

```
// OK (assuming there is no type constraint on the
//     generic placeholder in the definition of SomeStruct)
class SomeClass<T> {
    let someStruct: SomeStruct<T>
}
```

Finally, with regard to the "repeated" type constraints: if the generic placeholder for some given type, say `SomeStruct<T>` as in your question, is under some type constraint, then naturally (static typing) any typeholder "propagated" as generic type specifier in usages of the generic `SomeStruct` must be ensured to conform to the same constraints as those applied to the generic placeholder in `SomeStruct`. Hence, you cannot avoid specifying the same type constraints in the generic class `SomeClass<T: ...>` to which `SomeStruct` is used as a generically tied member.

```
struct SomeStruct<T : CustomStringConvertible> {
    let data: T
}

class SomeClass<T> {
    let someStruct: SomeStruct<T>
                            /* ^ this placeholder is not guaranteed to fulfil
                                 the type constraints which are applied to the
                                 generic typeholder of SomeStruct, hence the
                                 illegality */
}
```

Comment: Yea, but why does `SomeClass` have to be generic?  Can't it just simply *have* a generic property without being generic itself?  I don't see what's dangerous about that.  `SomeClass` doesn't need to know more about `data` other than what `SomeStruct` says will always be the case, that `data` will always be `CustomStringConvertible`.  In my example, I don't care for `SomeClass` to even know that `data` is `Int` in this usage.

Comment: @solidcell no, the same argument as in the top of my answer applies: if `SomeClass` is not generic, then it is a concrete type, and then all of its members must be concrete types. If you're set on working with generics, this is a rule that applies, propagating from one of the core concepts of Swift: its strong typing system.

Answer (score 0):

`CustomStringConvertible` is not a concrete type. The compiler can not infer what the base type (conforming to `CustomStringConvertible`) really is.

For this specific case, if the only capability `SomeClass` needs from `someStruct` is the ability to access `data` as a `String`, then you should simply convert your injected types (like `someStruct`) into strings first.

Comment: No, more is required from the struct in my actual use case.  This is just a simplified example to highlight the issue.